# Include/Exclude traffic to subdirectory when case sensitive and trailing slash

Tags: google-analytics

I have two views in Google Analytics:

1. Main View
2. /en/ View

I need to Include Only Traffic to /en/ view; however, the possible options for /en/ are:

```
/en/
/en
/En
/En/
```

I don't have option to fix case or trailing slash, could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you should be able to create a new profile (view) and apply a custom filter for Request URI and use a RegEx expression to include only /en/, /en, /En, and /En.

Should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Pretty much the same technique (With an advanced filter) could be used  to fix both the trailing slash and the case. If that happens before the include filter not only the traffic will be filtered by directory, it will also result in a more readable report (since /en, /en/ and /En etc point to the same directory they should appear as one url in the report).

Comment: Yes, you understand correct. Are you sure this will fire what I need?
\/en\/?
if it includes /En ?
And if you can, can you explain this string? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This won't fire anything, it will simply filter /en/, /en, /En, and /En into a profile. You can test the snippet of RegEx I gave you with a RegEx tester such as [ReGex Pal](http://regexpal.com/) - paste the snippet \/en\/? into the top textarea and put your subdirectories /en/, /en, /En, and /En into the bottom textarea. YOu'll see that the RegEx is matching all of your options for subdirectories.

Comment: Your solution is not working for me, I found this one works:


custom filter --> exclude --> reguest URI --> ^/en/|^/En